# Unable to install anything due to Dependency Problem

Tags: dependencies

[This message shows up everytime I try to install anything. Please good people, I am counting on Ubuntu. I can't go back to Windows. Please help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVg5D.png)

Comment: Have you tried installing the packages that the error messages are telling you are not installed?

Comment: Well, this is why you use software center fo apt-get to install packages rather then dpkg. run `sudo apt-get install -f` and you should be good to go.

Comment: You should really include the text of commands and messages in your question  rather than linking to saved screenshots which may be removed in future. You also need to learn to use Google. Assuming you are trying to install the Atom editor, I googled 'ubuntu atom' and the second result is instruction to install Atom which is to add the repository where Atom is maintained (`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/atom`) and then use apt (or apt-get) as others have suggested (`sudo apt update;sudo apt install atom`);.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is why you use software center or apt-get to install packages rather then dpkg. dpkg does NOT resolve dependencies.

You should NOT be downloading and installing random .deb from across the internet, use the ubuntu repositories.

See [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu) and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftwar

To install the dependencies, run:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

and you should be good to go.